# How to set limit in x- axis of core plot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

If i want to show only 10 points of date in x-axis and its corresponding value y axis in the graph. How can set in core plot scattered graph. Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are two properties called xRange and yRange under CPXYPlotSpace. You can use that for setting limits. For example,

```
CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPDecimalFromInt(10)];

plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromInt(5) length:CPDecimalFromInt(10)];
```

Comment: NSTimeInterval oneday= 60*60*24                        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
NSTimeInterval xLow = 0.0f; i want to show from current date till 10  date. is it possible?
contentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xLow)
length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay*50.f)];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(50.0)];
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction=YES;

Comment: There is no direct function to support it. You have to manually do it! Apply your math. I would simply suggest to start with your current date's day component and then add 10 to get the maximum limit. Use axis legend to mention your unit as day.